# UIColor become automatically black

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uicolor

I'm getting some trouble with UIColor.

So, I have a BackgroudColor that is White.

The user can choose a background color in the view by clicking some buttons

there is another button to go into a Color Picker View.

When he come back to the view, if he clicked the right button he should see his picked color.

And if he click on this button he should also see this color.

But he can't see it. There's still a black Color showing.

When the user click on picked color the float value come from (For red example) r: 1.0 g: 0.0 b: 0.0 to r: 0.0 g: 0.0 b: 0.0

I don't know how to do to keep the correct float values.

I hope i was clear enough.

Thanks :)

Comment: I need to to you also : On the pickerViewController the color generate 3 float value for red, green and blue, and i can send it to the RootViewController without problem.

Comment: do you have a retain problem?

Comment: Showing code might help!

Answer (score 0):

You must retain your r g b UIColor *color, otherwise it is autoreleased a bit later.
Colors components (r,g,b) must be specified in range 0.0 - 1.0.
Make sure that full red finaly calculates to r=1.0, g= 0, b= 0;

Store the current color in an float[4] array. (r,g,b,alpha) or float[3] for rgb only.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd better show your my code : for setting my backgroundColor i use return [UIColor colorWithRed:Green:Blue:Alpha:]; So the thing I need to retain is float. But I think we can't retain float values

Comment: no the color has to be retained, the caller of the method shoukd retain it, like all other objets. exceptions are only predefined colors like [UIcolor redColor]

Comment: @user1870600 UIColor *bg = myGetColor(); [bg retain];

Comment: backColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:self.redR green:self.greenG blue:self.blueB alpha:1.0f];
        [backColor retain];
        NSLog(@"%@ backColor", backColor); // result : UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.153846 0.153846 1
        return backColor;
And my background stay black. A if I click on the button once again the NSlog retur that my UICOlor is black

Comment: Your color looks, ok, the problem is the button. maybe you should set the foreground color of the button.

Comment: It also fail :/ My UIColor always become black. May you have Skype to see direct code ? I offer a code to get the app for free when she will be out :)

Comment: This is not black: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.153846 0.153846 1; This is red. You r button may not support back groun dor foreground; Check the docu on the button. Try to set the button color hard coded, does this work: button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; ifthat does not work then your button does not offer that.

Comment: I'm not trying to change my button's background color but my view's bgColor. I know that it is red. But when i click once again on the button it turn black (r: 0.0 g: 0.0 b: 0.0). And my backgroundcolor never change.

Comment: You have a problem in your program logic. Neither with UIColor nor with background. Use the debugger tho check why the float values turn th 0 the second time.